# How to make y-axis not start at zero?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I know there is a `chart.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false` option but it's not working for me.

I'm making a line graph to track Instagram Followers over time and I have data points that vary very little so I need the y-axis adjusted so that the changes are enabled, but it 
[image]

Here is the code I have for the graph:

```
let chart = LineChartView(frame: chart1View.bounds)
            let dayTrackerUnits = trackerCrawler.thisWeeksPoints()

            var xVals : [Int] = []
            var yVals : [ChartDataEntry] = []
            var minimum = 1000000000
            var maximum = 0
            for i in 0..<dayTrackerUnits.count {
                xVals.append(i)
                yVals.append(ChartDataEntry(value: Double(dayTrackerUnits[i].followerCount), xIndex: i))

                if dayTrackerUnits[i].followerCount < minimum {
                    minimum = dayTrackerUnits[i].followerCount
                }

                if dayTrackerUnits[i].followerCount > maximum {
                    maximum = dayTrackerUnits[i].followerCount
                }

            }

            print(yVals)

            let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals, label: "Followers")
            chartDataSet.setColor(GlobalStyles.sharedStyles.instagramBlue())
            chartDataSet.lineWidth = 2.0
            chartDataSet.circleRadius = 5.0
            chartDataSet.circleColors = [GlobalStyles.sharedStyles.instagramBlue()]
            chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
            chartDataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true

            let data = LineChartData(xVals: xVals, dataSet: chartDataSet)
            chart.data = data
            chart.delegate = self
            chart.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false
            chart.rightAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false
            print("min: \(minimum), max: \(maximum)")
            chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
            chart1View.addSubview(chart)
            left1Label.text = "Followers"
```

I'd like to set the `yAxisMinimum` to `minimum` and the `yAxisMaximum` to `maximum` but the graph won't display how I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `customAxisMin/Max` to limit its range.

BTW, you have to make sure your data values does not contains 0. It seems like your data has 0, that's why it always start from 0. It has a small algorithm to calculate the axis range in `computeAxisValues` in y axis renderer.